# how i can seperate only mobile number from this expression in notepad ++

Tags: notepad

```
103.199.145.50 - - [02/Jan/2020:04:42:34 +0530]
"GET /mspProducerM/sendSMS?user=userjesus&pwd=jcallshttp&sender=JCALLS&mobile9159525910&msg=Promise%20for%20Jan,%2002%20The%20Lord%20blesses%20His%20people%20with%20peace.-%20Psalm%2029:11.%20For%20Prayers%20and%20Queries%20call%20044-45999000&mt=0 
HTTP/1.1" 200 42
```

like i need to extract text, 9159525910

Comment: The portion of the query string which seems to contain the mobile number appears broken, because there is no key/value separated by an `=`.  Can you please double check your data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, `mobile=xxxx`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode, with DOT ALL enabled:

```
Find:   \b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ - - \[[^]]+\].*?".*?\bmobile=(\d+).*?" \d+ \d+
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

The approach here is to match the entire line of your input, and then capture the mobile number.  The replacement is just the captured phone number.

Comment: it says 0  occurance were asked

Comment: @neerajyadav Please try my updated answer, which is working in the demo.